# Check/Uncheck aspx checkbox using Css/Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox, aspxgridview

I am new to ASPX **GridView**. I have a column of checkbox.

I need to ***check/uncheck*** it using *Css/Jquery*

The HTML code for checkbox is as below:

```
<span class="dxICheckBox dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked" id="cbUploadXYZ_7_S_D">
  <span class="dxKBSW">
    <input id="cbUploadXYZ_7_S" name="ctl00$cphSiteBody$ctrlABCList$gvABCList$cell7_0$TC$cbUploadXYZ_7" value="I" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="opacity:0;width:1px;height:1px;position:relative;background-color:transparent;display:block;margin:0;padding:0;border-width:0;font-size:0pt;">
  </span>
</span>
```

I am checking the checkbox with code JQuery:

```
$($('#cbUploadUBS_7').find('span')[0]).removeClass("dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked").addClass("dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked");
```

But, when I click the above checked box, it remains checked on first click (should get unchecked on first click) and get uncheked on second click.

How can I apply CSS so that checkboxes work correctly?

Please help!

**Edit**
The above code is rendered due to following code in ASPX page.

```
<DataItemTemplate>
  <div style="text-align: center">
      <dx:ASPxCheckBox OnInit="abcListCheckBox_Init" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
          <ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="SetCount" />
      </dx:ASPxCheckBox>
  </div>
```

Comment: which checkbox? i don't see one in the markup.

Comment: @Jai Please check my Edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have posted a wrong markup or may be this is a typo because the posted on has `type="text"` and it isn't a checkbox.
I guess you should use `.toggleClass(cls1 cls2)`:

```
$('#cbUploadUBS_7')
  .children('span') // change to children
  .toggleClass("dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked");
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
var id = "cbUploadUBS_7";
var chkBoxControl = aspxGetControlCollection().Get(id);
chkBoxControl.SetCheckState('Checked');
$($('#' + id).find('span'[0]).removeClass("dxWeb_edtCheckBoxUnchecked").addClass("dxWeb_edtCheckBoxChecked");
```